# How to groupby set of columns also grouping by a column with combinations of its items and aggregate on the value column?

Tags: pandas, numpy, math, group-by, combinations

Here is the dataframe [image: Input df]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'county':['Laramie']*10 + ['Albany']*12,
                   'co': ['LU']*22,
                    'tech':['cable']*6+['copper']*4+['cable']*6+['copper']*4+['Fiber']*2,
                    'loc':[*'abcdefdefgmnopqrnostow']})
```

I want to groupby on county, co, and all the combinations of the items from tech column and aggregate on loc column to get the unique and nunique.

Here is the result I am looking for:
[image: Output df]

Tried this:

```
df = df.groupby(['county', 'co'], as_index=True).agg({'tech':'unique', 'loc':'unique', 'loc':'nunique'}).reset_index()
```

But this doesn't give out all the possible combinations of the tech column.

Comment: Is it supposed to be log or loc? This isn't consistent.

Comment: Why is there no output `tech` value with a single item? Why is e.g. "only cable" not allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a partial [`powerset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

# modified powerset recipe
def powerset(iterable, min=0):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(min, len(s)+1))

group = ['county', 'co']

tmp = df.groupby(['tech', *group])['loc'].agg(set)

out = []
for k, g in tmp.groupby(group):
    for x in map(list, powerset(g.index.get_level_values('tech'), min=2)):
        out.append(dict(zip(group, k))
                  |{'tech': ', '.join(x),
                    'log': (s:=set().union(*g.loc[x])),
                    'log-nunique': len(s),
                   })

out = pd.DataFrame(out)
```

*NB. this uses the walrus operator (`:=`, python ≥3.8) and dictionary union (`{}|{}`, python ≥3.9), none of which are strictly required, the code can be adapted for older python versions*.*

Output:

```
    county  co                  tech                          log  log-nunique
0   Albany  LU          Fiber, cable        {o, n, m, r, q, w, p}            7
1   Albany  LU         Fiber, copper              {o, n, s, t, w}            5
2   Albany  LU         cable, copper     {o, n, m, s, r, q, t, p}            8
3   Albany  LU  Fiber, cable, copper  {o, n, m, s, r, q, t, w, p}            9
4  Laramie  LU         cable, copper        {b, a, c, e, f, g, d}            7
```

* code for older python:

```
group = ['county', 'co']

tmp = df.groupby(['tech', 'county', 'co'])['loc'].agg(set)

out = []
for k, g in tmp.groupby(['county', 'co']):
    for x in map(list, powerset(g.index.get_level_values('tech'), min=2)):
        out.append({'county': k[0],
                    'co': k[1],
                    'tech': ', '.join(x),
                    'log': set().union(*g.loc[x]),
                   })
        out[-1]['log-nunique'] = len(out[-1]['log'])

out = pd.DataFrame(out)
```

Comment: Would this code be efficient to work on large dataset?

Comment: @Rac in terms of generating the data, I believe it's as efficient as it can be with python. However, keep in mind that generating combinations might give a much larger output that the input. In particular if you have many "tech" within a group, and no matter the algorithm or programming language. What if the number of groups and the max number of unique "tech" per group?

Comment: I'm doing initial performance tests on a frame of 100,000, and this method is about an order of magnitude slower than the vectorised one. I'll post more detail once I have it.

Comment: This solution is very efficient. Thanks @mozway.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in a nearly-fully-vectorised way. Vectorisation breaks down when you want lists in cells, which is generally a bad idea in Pandas; nevertheless:

```py
import cProfile
import pstats
from timeit import timeit
import seaborn as sns

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def op_data() -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Sample data more or less the same as OP"""
    return pd.DataFrame({
        'county': ['Laramie']*10 + ['Albany']*12,
        'co': ['LU']*22,
        'tech': ['cable']*6 + ['copper']*4 + ['cable']*6 + ['copper']*4 + ['fibre']*2,
        'loc': list('abcdefdefgmnopqrnostow'),
    })


def big_data(
    rand: np.random.Generator,
    n: int = 2_000,
    group_frac: int = 0.1,
    n_locs: int = 26,
    tech_dist: float = 0.33,
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    techs = np.full(shape=n, fill_value='copper')
    tech_asn = rand.random(size=n)
    techs[tech_asn > tech_dist] = 'cable'
    techs[tech_asn > tech_dist*0.5 + 0.5] = 'fibre'

    group_size = group_frac*n

    return pd.DataFrame({
        'county': np.linspace(start=0, stop=n/10, num=n, dtype=int),
        'co': np.linspace(start=0, stop=n/group_size, num=n, dtype=int),
        'tech': techs,
        'loc': rand.integers(low=0, high=n_locs, size=n),
    })


def notna_tuple(col: pd.Series) -> tuple:
    return tuple(col.dropna())


def agg_tech(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # One-hot boolean columns for tech assignments
    tech_vals = df['tech'].unique()
    df[tech_vals] = pd.DataFrame(
        data=np.equal.outer(df['tech'].values, tech_vals),
        columns=tech_vals, index=df.index,
    )

    # Cartesian product of all tech values
    tech_combos = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((
        pd.Index(name=tech, data=(False, True))
        for tech in tech_vals
    )).to_frame()

    # each group must have at least two tech values in the combination
    tech_combos = tech_combos[tech_combos[tech_vals].sum(axis=1) > 1]

    # Make tech name tuples
    names = pd.DataFrame(index=tech_combos.index)
    names[tech_vals] = tech_vals
    names[~tech_combos[tech_vals].values] = np.nan
    tech_combos['name'] = names.agg(notna_tuple, axis=1)

    # Cartesian product of all tech values and all county-co groups,
    # where each group must have at least two tech values in the combination
    tech_combos = pd.merge(
        # For each county-co group, for each tech: is there at least one of that tech?
        left=df.groupby(['county', 'co'])[tech_vals]
        .any().reset_index(),
        right=tech_combos,
        how='cross', suffixes=['_any', '']
    )

    # Eliminate county-co/tech pairs where the tech combo uses a missing tech
    tech_combos = tech_combos.loc[
        (
            tech_combos[tech_vals] <= tech_combos[tech_vals + '_any'].values
        ).all(axis=1),
        ['county', 'co', 'name', *tech_vals],
    ]

    # loc values for every tech combination
    tech_combos = pd.merge(
        left=tech_combos, right=df,
        on=['county', 'co'], suffixes=['_group', ''],
    )

    tech_combos = (
        tech_combos.loc[
            (
                # eliminate rows for which the tech combination does not match
                tech_combos[tech_vals] <= tech_combos[tech_vals + '_group'].values
            ).all(axis=1),
            ['county', 'co', 'name', 'loc'],
        ]
        .drop_duplicates()
        .groupby(['county', 'co', 'name'])
        .agg([tuple, 'count'])
        .reset_index()
    )

    return tech_combos


def powerset(iterable, min=0):
    """modified powerset recipe"""
    s = list(iterable)
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(s, r) for r in range(min, len(s)+1))


def mozway(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    group = ['county', 'co']

    tmp = df.groupby(['tech', *group])['loc'].agg(set)

    out = []
    for k, g in tmp.groupby(group):
        for x in map(list, powerset(g.index.get_level_values('tech'), min=2)):
            out.append(dict(zip(group, k))
                      |{'tech': ', '.join(x),
                        'log': (s:=set().union(*g.loc[x])),
                        'log-nunique': len(s),
                       })

    return pd.DataFrame(out)


def test() -> None:
    print(agg_tech(op_data()))
    print(mozway(op_data()))


def plot() -> None:
    rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
    methods = (agg_tech, mozway)
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

    print('By n...')
    by_n = []
    for n in (10**(np.linspace(1.5, 4, num=20))).astype(int):
        inp_orig = big_data(rand, n=n)
        for method in methods:
            inp = inp_orig.copy()
            def run():
                return method(inp)
            dur = timeit(stmt=run, number=1)
            by_n.append((n, method.__name__, dur))

    sns.lineplot(pd.DataFrame(by_n, columns=('n', 'method', 'dur')),
                 x='n', y='dur', hue='method', ax=axes[0][0])
    axes[0][0].set(xscale='log', yscale='log')

    print('By group_frac...')
    by_frac = []
    for frac in np.linspace(0, 0.5, num=20):
        inp_orig = big_data(rand, group_frac=frac)
        for method in methods:
            inp = inp_orig.copy()
            def run():
                return method(inp)
            dur = timeit(stmt=run, number=1)
            by_frac.append((frac, method.__name__, dur))

    sns.lineplot(pd.DataFrame(by_frac, columns=('group_frac', 'method', 'dur')),
                 x='group_frac', y='dur', hue='method', ax=axes[0][1])

    print('By n_locs...')
    by_locs = []
    for n_locs in np.linspace(1, 200, num=20, dtype=int):
        inp_orig = big_data(rand, n_locs=n_locs)
        for method in methods:
            inp = inp_orig.copy()
            def run():
                return method(inp)
            dur = timeit(stmt=run, number=1)
            by_locs.append((n_locs, method.__name__, dur))

    sns.lineplot(pd.DataFrame(by_locs, columns=('n_locs', 'method', 'dur')),
                 x='n_locs', y='dur', hue='method', ax=axes[1][0])

    print('By tech dist...')
    by_tech = []
    for tech_dist in np.linspace(0.05, 0.95, num=20):
        inp_orig = big_data(rand, tech_dist=tech_dist)
        for method in methods:
            inp = inp_orig.copy()
            def run():
                return method(inp)
            dur = timeit(stmt=run, number=1)
            by_tech.append((tech_dist, method.__name__, dur))

    sns.lineplot(pd.DataFrame(by_tech, columns=('tech_dist', 'method', 'dur')),
                 x='tech_dist', y='dur', hue='method', ax=axes[1][1])
    axes[1][1].set(yscale='log')

    plt.show()


def profile():
    rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
    df = big_data(rand, n=100_000)

    pr = cProfile.Profile()
    pr.enable()
    agg_tech(df)
    pr.disable()
    ps = pstats.Stats(pr).sort_stats('cumulative')
    ps.print_stats(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
    profile()
    plot()
```

```
    county  co                    name                          loc      
                                                              tuple count
0   Albany  LU         (cable, copper)     (m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t)     8
1   Albany  LU  (cable, copper, fibre)  (m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, w)     9
2   Albany  LU          (cable, fibre)        (m, n, o, p, q, r, w)     7
3   Albany  LU         (copper, fibre)              (n, o, s, t, w)     5
4  Laramie  LU         (cable, copper)        (a, b, c, d, e, f, g)     7
```

This always outperforms the nonvectorised version for any input greater than about 100 elements; by how much depends mostly on the distribution of tech values:

[image: perf comparison]

Note that by far the longest operation is `agg(tuple)`. If you can tolerate a different output, such as

- a long-form table with one entry per `loc`, or
- a short-form table that only has the unique count, or
- a wide-form table with `loc`-or-NaN in columns,

this will be much, much faster. For instance, for the last option you could use this routine:

```py
def agg_tech(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # One-hot boolean columns for tech assignments
    tech_vals = df['tech'].unique()
    df[tech_vals] = pd.DataFrame(
        data=np.equal.outer(df['tech'].values, tech_vals),
        columns=tech_vals, index=df.index,
    )

    # Cartesian product of all tech values
    tech_combos = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((
        pd.Index(name=tech, data=(False, True))
        for tech in tech_vals
    )).to_frame()

    # each group must have at least two tech values in the combination
    tech_combos = tech_combos[tech_combos[tech_vals].sum(axis=1) > 1]

    # Make tech name tuples
    names = pd.DataFrame(index=tech_combos.index)
    names[tech_vals] = tech_vals
    names[~tech_combos[tech_vals].values] = np.nan
    tech_combos['name'] = names.agg(notna_tuple, axis=1)

    grouped = df.groupby(['county', 'co'])

    df['group_idx'] = grouped.cumcount()

    # Cartesian product of all tech values and all county-co groups,
    # where each group must have at least two tech values in the combination
    tech_combos = pd.merge(
        # For each county-co group, for each tech: is there at least one of that tech?
        left=grouped[tech_vals]
        .any().reset_index(),
        right=tech_combos,
        how='cross', suffixes=['_any', '']
    )

    # Eliminate county-co/tech pairs where the tech combo uses a missing tech
    tech_combos = tech_combos.loc[
        (
            tech_combos[tech_vals] <= tech_combos[tech_vals + '_any'].values
        ).all(axis=1),
        ['county', 'co', 'name', *tech_vals],
    ]

    # loc values for every tech combination
    tech_combos = pd.merge(
        left=tech_combos, right=df,
        on=['county', 'co'], suffixes=['_group', ''],
    )

    tech_combos = (
        tech_combos.loc[
            (
                # eliminate rows for which the tech combination does not match
                tech_combos[tech_vals] <= tech_combos[tech_vals + '_group'].values
            ).all(axis=1),
            ['county', 'co', 'name', 'group_idx', 'loc'],
        ]
        .set_index(['county', 'co', 'name', 'group_idx'])
        .unstack('group_idx')
    )

    return tech_combos
```

for about a 10x speedup.

Comment: Using a cross-merge to then filter is most often inefficient, especially since you used broadcasting. Have you tested it on a large dataset?

Comment: Depends on a lot of things OP has not specified, including data size, proportion of tech values per group, etc. If I were to attempt a large dataset I'd be flying blind and it would be a waste of time without more information.

Comment: Its an extremely large dataset consisting of  around 100 million + rows, not sure about the proportion of the tech values per group.

Comment: @Rac I don't have the patience to test out 100M rows, so I've demonstrated with up to 10,000.

Comment: @mozway So I have tried, now; and for a few reasons - the inefficiency of non-vectorised operations in Python, as well as the relatively low rejection ratio of the post-cross-join filter, this is not inefficient.